# Calculus(power series)

Tags: power-series

Hi could anyone help me solve this problem.(without expanding the function). I cant seem to get it.

Express the function as a power series

$$\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$$

I managed to split the $\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)$ apart but i do not know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Can you write $\ln (1+x)$ as a power series?

Comment: Yes but the question i do not know  how to combine the Ln(1+x) and ln(1-x) together without expanding them.

Comment: If both series do not diverge, you can sum them term by term

Comment: One way to do it "without expanding the function" is: (1) Take derivative of the original function, (2) You will get a rational function which you can expand in series by decomposing in partial fractions and then expanding each of them in series, (3) integrate the series you obtained. (5) But is too much work that wasn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on
$$ln(1+x)=\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ { \left( -1 \right)  }^{ n-1 } } \frac { { x }^{ n } }{ n } ,\quad \left| x \right| <1$$
we get 
$$ln(1-x)=-\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { { x }^{ n } }{ n }  } ,\quad \left| x \right| <1$$

Therefore,

$$ln\frac { 1+x }{ 1-x } =2\sum _{ k=0 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { x^{ 2k+1 } }{ 2k+1 }  } ,\quad \left| x \right| <1$$

Comment: I know it's a bit pedantic, but could you take this like one more step and simplify $1+(-1)^{n-1}$?

Comment: thanks kitter, I changed my answer.